# Handling roots of Cubic Equations in C programming

Tags: c, cubic

The program outputs the same value for any i or initial guess from printf.  The question asks for the root at a given i which is always different.  How can we carry over Xo for the X at 0 in our equation of (1-x^3) we have the value of 1.  This value should carry over to the calculation for x=2, x=3, and so on to output unique values of the roots.
Also, **my** manipulation of the equation in the code below may not be what the logic requires.  I need to show the initial value carrying over as shown in bold from the general expression for a cubic root in the **original question**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int i;
float x;
printf("Enter initial guess =");scanf("%f",&x);
for (i=0;i<100;i++) x=(1-pow(x,3));
printf("%f\n",x);
return 0;
}
```

**The Original Question:**

We want to find one of the roots of a cubic equation given by ((x)^3)+x-1 = 0 which is between 0 and 1 by an iterative method.

Modify the equation above to x=1/(1+(x^2)).  /*This question is ambiguous to me.*/

Start with an appropriate initial value and do the iteration above until it is convergent.

For example, 
Xo(initial value???) = **0.5**, X1 = 1/(1+(**0.5**^2) = **0.8**, 
X2 = 1/(1+**0.8**^2)=**0.609**

**The simplest (minimum) code may look like:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main()
{
int i;
float x;
printf("Enter initial guess =");scanf("%f",&x);
for (i=0;i<100;i++) /* insert your iteration code
*/
printf("%f
\
n",x);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed tag from c# to c

Comment: *013=−+xx? 211xx+=? 8.05.011,5.0210=+==xx ,609.08.01122=+=x ,728.0609.01123=+=x?* To my eye, this looks like line noise. Please work on the clarity of your question.

Comment: I apologize.  We were rushing off to get food.  Fixing it now...